# How can I use multiple functions with the same name in other C files if they have the same name and I can't modify the other files?

Tags: c, linker

I have program which generates C files containing a single function `void foo(float* n) {}`. The files have different code within the function but the name is always the same. I want to create a C file which runs them all in turn but when I try to include more than one I get a redefinition error (from the linker?). I can't change the C files that are produced (otherwise I would just change the function name). The files generated all have different and unique names even though the functions all have common names, and I only need to use the functions one at a time (if there is any sort of freeing operation like #undef for macros).

Comment: A couple of possible solutions. 1. During compliation, redefine `foo` with a file specific name. e.g. `gcc -c foo1.c -Dfoo=foo1` or 2. Use `dlopen`, `dlsym` and `dlclose` to open each object, get the `foo` address and call that function for each file.

Comment: Would declaring the functions static help? That would prevent linker issues, but then you'd need something unique to each C file to call the common function.

Comment: @rcgldr The problem with that is that I cannot change the files being emitted by the generator in order to make them static. Otherwise I would have just changed the function names.

Comment: Are you compiling them yourself? Wouldn't you be able to modify them after they are generated then?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the preprocessor to change the function name for each file at compile-time, e.g.

```
$ gcc -Wall -Dfoo=foo_1 -c bar1.c
$ gcc -Wall -Dfoo=foo_2 -c bar2.c
$ gcc -Wall -Dfoo=foo_3 -c bar3.c
$ gcc -Wall main.c bar1.o bar2.o bar3.o
```

This way you can call functions `foo_1()`, `foo_2()`, `foo_3()` from `main()`.